# Go throught mySQL DB iteration and convert strings into different encoding

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I've received from a friend a DB backup of a Wordpress blog that had been given to her. The person who did the backup before obviously did something wrong, as all the accented character in the blog posts are badly encoded and echoes like "Ã©" or "Ã€".

Now, I though about a "simple" script that would loop through the DB, look for given string of badly encoded character and convert them to what it should be. But I guess it's not really the best way to do it. I know that there is character encoding functions in PHP, but I'm not at all versed into theses, as I don't really understand the mechanics of character encoding.

Anyone can help me on this?

Comment: what's the db character encoding currently set to? and the browser\webpage?

Comment: Receiving BD collation is set to utf8_unicode_ci. As for browser webpage, phpMyAdmin' source gives me utf8, as does Wordpress' sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal if you look at the dump file from an text editor with a single-byte encoding: multibyte UTF-8 characters will show up as two-byte pairs like those you show.

You should be able to specify the dump's character set when importing (e.g. using the appropriate drop-down in phpMyAdmin). Set the character set to UTF-8 and it should import properly.

Comment: I though about that, but I gave it an another try, just to make sure. Selecting either UTF8 or latin (1,2,5 or 7) before importing just won't do it either. The character in the BD (and in the Wordpress output) still come out wrongly encoded ! :(

Answer (score 0):

Potentially you have double encoded UTF-8. You might try re-dumping the database as latin1, and re-importing as UTF-8. [src](http://blog.hno3.org/2010/04/22/fixing-double-encoded-utf-8-data-in-mysql/)

Comment: Sadly, I can't do this. The story is that a friend of mine was hosted somewhere freely by a friend or her. That said friend decided he wouldn't host anything anymore, so he backed up everything quickly, sent the files and deleted everything. The sql file I have is the last remaining copy of the original DB that got exported before deletion ! :(

Comment: no I mean, dump the file as latin1 from your database and then re-import that dumpfile (instead of the one your friend provided). Could be an effort in futility, but why not try? :)

Comment: Ok, just to check if I follow your idea: take the SQL file, import it as UTF-8, dump as latin-1, then reimport as latin-1 ? It is worth a try, yes! :)